# MySQL condition for false status

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I have a MySQL query as follows which is used to outs the stock balance of items

```
SELECT
    
    item_name,
    item_id,
    unit_price,
    store_sub_type.sub_type_name,
    store_item.pg_no,
    
    CASE WHEN  order_status = 'purchase' THEN  qty else 0  end as purchase ,    
    CASE WHEN  order_status ='issue'  THEN  qty else 0  end as issues,
    CASE WHEN  store_update_stock.status != 0 and transfer_status !='Pending' and transfer_status !='Recomended' THEN  qty else 0 
    end as balance
    
    from store_update_stock
    inner join store_update_stock_details on store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id
    left join store_item on store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id
    left join store_sub_type on store_sub_type.sub_type_name=store_item.item_sub_type
    
    where store_update_stock.status=1 and store_item.usr != 'doaso' and unit_price > 0
```

2. The query is working fine. But the report includes items with zero balances. I do not want to show the items from the list with zero balances.
3. How can I change the query to do that ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `WHERE ... AND balance >0` ? isn't working?

Comment: @ Alex. Yes. WHERE ... AND balance >0 isn't working. Because balance is not a actual table column. it is a virtual column. See on my query again

Answer (score 1):

If your current query gives you the results you want, and you just want to filter out rows whose `balance` is `0`, then you can turn it to a subquery, and filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    -- your current query here
) t
where balance <> 0
```